# How can I tell where I have clicked on a Telerik Winform gridview?

Tags: c#, telerik

I am clicking on the scrollbar on the Telerik gridview (sorry Telerik but your online help is not the best) and I want to know where the user has clicked so I can respond appropriately for example if the user clicks on the scroll bar or headers then I wont look up a row value etc

thanks

Comment: Not sure about the scroll bar, but use the standard cell click handler and then look at the cell *type* (the cell is passed as an argument) to determine what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the help, we also have online support for these kind of stuff.

I am taking for example RadRichBox, but it works for any other control.

```
this.radRichTextBox1.MouseClick += radRichTextBox1_MouseClick;
private void radRichTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            RadMessageBox.Show(e.Location.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: thanks. I remember searching when I posted and I could not find any examples. Would like to see an example in your online help - posted before or after the date of my post that shows if the user clicked on a valid cell. The location I think refers to a point (x or y) and this is not much help..I need to know if the user clicked on a cell in a row and which cell/row it is